# Bitcoin Integration with bitcoin core api without any third party api

Tags: bitcoin

I am trying to integrate the bitcoin API into my application. I am already using ripple API ( those are very simple and well documented ).

But now i want to integrate bitcoin API and i am very confuse where to start.

As per official bitcoin docs, install a bitcoin application and that application will download all transactions from very starting from 2009 and data size will be around 205GB. it too much.

I want to integrate without any third party api help. is there any api address of bitcoin just like ripple where i can hit request and get result.

Comment: I slightly reworded your question for readability, but well: it is too broad, and doesn't fit the scope of this community. You should turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask, and improve this question to be in the scope of this community.

Comment: You do not need to keep the entire blockchain for wallet applications. You can run a pruned node if you only send and receive bitcoins. Set `prune=550` in bitcoin.conf. The total disk usage runs to about 5 GB. You only need the full blockchain if you want to look up arbitrary transactions of other people, not related to your own transactions.

Answer (score -1):

[Bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bitcoin-core-apis) provides well documented references regarding API calls.